# Using lambda to return a boolean inside if else statement

Tags: c++, lambda

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    bool gg;
    if( [&]()->decltype(gg){

    return false;  //try changing this to true or false and you'll get the same result.

    } ){

    std::cout<<"all even"<<std::endl;   
    }else {
    std::cout<<"all odd"<<std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

It's just simple, i have an if else statement and a lambda function inside it that checks the condition. I don't know if it's the code or compiler but even if i change false to true and vice versa, i get the same result. I am using Dev CPP. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: well if you wrote the same code with a named function: `if (returnFalse) { …}` what would you expect? If you don't **call** the function, how do you expect a return value out of it?

Comment: ... I don't quite understand why this even compiles. Must be another gcc extension.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows lack of research and of understanding of fundamentals of the language.

Comment: @dyp not necessarily, you can do the same thing with function pointers…

Comment: It does implicit cast from function pointer to bool, which is pretty dangerous. VS actually refuses to compile that code.

Comment: @dyp [expr.prim.lambda]/2 "[a lambda] behaves like a function object", and function objects are implicitly convertible to bool

Comment: @MattMcNabb No, function objects are not implicitly convertible to bool. A function object is simply something that can be called, like some `struct foo { void operator()(); };`

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Only lambdas *without capture* are convertible to function pointers. This lambda is not convertible to a function pointer, and clang++ complains about the OP's code.

Comment: @dyp OK fair enough. AnT's answer explains it correctly.

Comment: @dyp I never asserted that it was convertible to a function pointer. I merely suggested that since function pointers are contextually convertible to `bool`, I wouldn't be surprised if lambdas (regardless of whether capturing or not) would be able to behave similarly (there's no logical reason why an existent function object should not be able to be contextually converted to bool). But granted, `clang++` is most probably right.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Ok, I've misunderstood your remark. But the analogy in this case does not apply; a lambda is an object of class type which is not convertible to `bool` directly.

Comment: @dyp Yes, you're right – that's why I formulated my original sentence as "not necessarily". It doesn't *have to* be true, but it apparently *is* true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **5.1.2 Lambda expressions**
>
> **6** The closure type for a lambda-expression with no lambda-capture has a public non-virtual non-explicit const conversion
> function to pointer to function having the same parameter and return
> types as the closure type’s function call operator. The value returned
> by this conversion function shall be the address of a function that,
> when invoked, has the same effect as invoking the closure type’s
> function call operator.

That is exactly what happens in your case. You forgot to invoke your closure object's `()` operator. Instead you used the closure object itself as a condition in `if`.

Since your closure object does not capture anything, per 5.1.2/6 it is implicitly convertible to plain function pointer type `bool (*)()`. And so your object got implicitly converted to a function pointer. Since the pointer is not null, it acts as `true` under `if`.

On other words, your code is interpreted by the compiler in the following way

```
bool gg;
auto lf = [&]() -> decltype(gg) { return false; };

bool (*f)() = lf;
if (f) {
  ...
```

If you make your lambda function actually capture something (e.g. replace `return false;` with `return gg;`), your original code will immediately fail to compile.

P.S. As you can read in the comments below, the very presence of `[&]` apparently should have disabled 5.1.2/6 for your lambda. But apparently your compiler treats 5.1.2/6 more loosely and looks for actual captures instead of simply checking for presence of non-`[]` capture clause.

Comment: OOoo alright. no wonder it got evaluated and i didnt get any error.

Comment: @dyp this paragraph doesn't exclude capturing lambdas from having the conversion; it only defines the behaviour for non-capturing lambdas.

Comment: Ok, checked again: I was right, this lambda is not convertible to a function pointer. It does have a capture, and clang++ complains about it. g++ accepts it, which is an extension.

Comment: That is, a *capture-default* grammatically **is** a *lambda-capture*. Hence, this lambda does have a *lambda-capture* and is not convertible to a function pointer. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b938c774611398a

Comment: @MattMcNabb See p3. An implementation is not allowed to add such a conversion. You can observe whether or not the conversion exists via SFINAE-reflection.

Comment: @dyp is the line "An implementation shall not add members of rvalue reference type to the closure type." also redundant then, since you could inspect the presence of any such named member in the same way?

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm not sure if you can detect the presence of private data members. Adding members of rvalue ref type makes the lambda noncopyable. (In C++11, all lambdas were copyable; in C++14, see http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue2095 )

Answer (score 5):

You don't evaluate the lambda, you just check the object:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    bool gg;
    if( [&]()->decltype(gg){

    return false;  //try changing this to true or false and you'll get the same result.

    }() == true){

    std::cout<<"all even"<<std::endl;   
    }else {
    std::cout<<"all odd"<<std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

edit: Ideone code https://ideone.com/yxloQf

Comment: Doesn't it get evaluated already since it returned a true or false?

Comment: @CarloBrew *evaluating* a function is different to *calling* it. It's the same error as: `bool f();  if ( f ) {` instead of `if ( f() ) {`

Comment: Oh alright, i forgot lambda's aren't automatically called unless it's something like std transform.

Comment: Just to be clear: I added == true because I feel this is clearer but what was really missing was the parenthesis after the brackets. This evaluates the lambda and ask "is the return value true?" without it it means "does this lambda object is convertible to boolean and is this boolean true?" which is different and does not evaluate the lambda.

Comment: @CarloBrew they are never "called automatically". Higher-order functions (such as `std::transform()`) call the supplied callbacks/transformation functions explicitly as well.