# Lambda expression to return bool in if statement

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

Just to get to the point, I want to return `true` or `false` using the lambda expression inside the `if()` statement. I saw this question which has similar question to mine: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602985/using-lambda-to-return-a-boolean-inside-if-else-statement) but I could not find the answer.

So here is my example code:

```
if([&rel_pose](Eigen::VectorXd pose)
    {
        return (sqrt(pose(0) * pose(0) + pose(1) * pose(1)) < 2) ? true : false;
    }) // do smth
```

When I try to compile I get this error:

```
 error: could not convert ‘<lambda closure object>graphslam::GraphSLAM::main_pose_callback(const ConstPtr&)::<lambda(Eigen::VectorXd)>{rel_pose}’ from ‘graphslam::GraphSLAM::main_pose_callback(const ConstPtr&)::<lambda(Eigen::VectorXd)>’ to ‘bool’
  })
```

Ok, reading the error I thought that I did not call the function as the compiler does not treat the expression as bool. So I tried to use this code:

```
if(([&rel_pose](Eigen::VectorXd pose)
    {
        return (sqrt(pose(0) * pose(0) + pose(1) * pose(1)) < 2) ? true : false;
    };)) // do smth
```

And the error:

```
expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
  };)) return;
```

That might look like an obvious error but for me, I probably do not understand the syntax correctly and thought to ask what is happening.

EDIT:
Please note that I have simplified the code so you can replicate the error easily. I know that lambda expression in this particular case does not make any sense.

Comment: you are just defining the lambda, not calling that.
Try to call the function.
Hint: `lack of ()` ;)

Comment: Defining a lambda makes no sense in that place at all. In the if expression you should directly execute the comparison expression, no need for a lambda around. You *can* define the lambda and execute it immediately , but that is total obscure coding,

Comment: @Klaus Yes you are right, I just simplified the example so people could replicate the error easily.

Comment: why you don't just `return sqrt(pose(0) * pose(0) + pose(1) * pose(1)) < 2;` without unnessesary `? true : false` ?

Comment: @Raffallo Just explained to Klaus

Comment: @aikhs - You might want to edit that explanation into the post. Otherwise you are bound to be asked this over and over.

Comment: @Klaus Why do you think that way? I cannot give a full example as people would need to install additional unnecessary libraries. The question in my opinion fully demonstrates the error and people could learn in future how to invoke lambda inside if statement. So I disagree with you in this case

Comment: @aikhs no, no :) I'm not talking about lambda, but your returning statement. You check if comparison gives true and you return true, and when comparison returns false you return false, but you can immediately return the comparison result :)

Comment: @Klaus - Three people managed to understand the Q just fine. It is not our place to go over the OP's "real code". They reduced it (could have reduced more though), and we answer.

Comment: And voting to close this as unclear is just bad faith use of a voting privilege. There is nothing unclear here. Get over yourself people.

Comment: @aikhs The comparison `sqrt(pose(0) * pose(0) + pose(1) * pose(1)) < 2` gives you bool type value, that can you return directly, you don't need to check that this bool value is true or false :)

Comment: @Klaus "Reducing a code example for a question to a useless example" is exactly what one should do. However, one should also not miss to explain what is the essential part and what part is simply due to simplicifaction and has to be taken as is because the real usefulnes can only be fully understood in the actual code, which should not be posted, but only a minimal example

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 If someone know that it makes no sense anymore, it is a good point to start to think about a useful one :-)

Comment: @Klaus maybe read here [mcve]. Examples here are not supposed to be useful, but they should be minimal, complete and verifiable. If they meet this criteria, then they are definitely useful because they help to find a solution to a given problem

Comment: @aikhs: Sorry for my unclear statement. I think you should give a reduced example, but put it in a more useful scenario. That's my point.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: The surrounding "if" statement makes the question unclear to me. If it comes with executing the lambda in any useful scenario, I can catch the point faster. Here I did not know if having a lambda is the bad thing or the missing execution of it. That can be done more efficient for the reader I believe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you forgot to call your lambda. Right now you're saying `if(function_pointer)` hence the compiler failing to convert that into a boolean expression.

---

A simple `if` clause with boolean lambda is therefore written like:

```
if ([]() {
    return true;
}()) {
    //do sth
}
```

---

You also have an error by having a variable be a parameter while simultaneously capturing it. You have to decide, so either:

```
if([](Eigen::VectorXd pose)
    {
        return (sqrt(pose(0) * pose(0) + pose(1) * pose(1)) < 2) ? true : false;
    }(rel_pose)){
    //do sth
}
```

or

```
if([&rel_pose]()
    {
        return (sqrt(rel_pose(0) * rel_pose(0) + rel_pose(1) * rel_pose(1)) < 2) ? true : false;
    }()){
    //do sth
}
```

---

The need of a lambda is in this case questionable, you could just get rid of the lamdba leaving the boolean expression in the if clause. When talking about it - no need to use a ternary operator here. `return sqrt(rel_pose(0) * rel_pose(0) + rel_pose(1) * rel_pose(1)) < 2;` is sufficient and more readable.

Comment: better than putting formulas in conditions is giving them semantics. `bool condition_name = (...); if( condition_name ){ ... }`

Answer (score 3):

A lambda is a function object. You should invoke it with `()`.

```
if ([](Eigen::VectorXd pose)
    {
        return (sqrt(pose(0) * pose(0) + pose(1) * pose(1)) < 2) ? true : false;
    }(rel_pose)) { /* ... */ }
```

You pass `rel_pose` as an argument instead of capturing it.
You should probably make `pose` a `const` reference anyway.

That said, I don't know what you are trying to do here. This would be better:

```
if (sqrt(foo(0) * foo(0) + foo(1) * foo(1)) < 2) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: How can you say what's better in general if you don't know the application? If you are talking specifically about the sample in the post, it should be stated explicitly.

Comment: @StoryTeller TBH, I can't think of a case in which an ad-hoc immediately called lambda would make more sense ...

Comment: Limited imagination is a bad foundation for absolute advice.

Comment: @StoryTeller Can you shed some light on it? ;-)

Comment: I just shed some light on it. Humility in assuming one doesn't know all ends is a virtue. But it's your answer, and your prerogative. I just said my piece about what bothered me.

Comment: @L.F. Just the other day I had to write a constructor as `C::C() : memb([]{ Obj x; f_sideffect_on(x); return x; }()) {}` because there was no `Obj f()`, but just `void f_sideeffect_on(Obj&)`.

Answer (score 3):

this is defining a lambda with capture phrase, not calling lambda

```
[&rel_pose](Eigen::VectorXd pose)
{
  return (sqrt(pose(0) * pose(0) + pose(1) * pose(1)) < 2) ? true : false;
}
```

if you want to call lambda with rel_pose as argument,

```
[](Eigen::VectorXd pose)
{
  return (sqrt(pose(0) * pose(0) + pose(1) * pose(1)) < 2) ? true : false;
}(rel_pose)
```

i think this is right