# while loop runs even if condition isnt true

Tags: c++

i am trying to make a calculator using c++, im trying to implement error handling, so if the user enters a non arithmetic operator, it will tell the user to please enter an operator, using a while loop. the problem is, even when the user enters an operator on the first run through, the while loop still executes.

I have tried not putting a space between while, and the perinthesis, also, i tried not using a variable, and just putting all the conditionals to trigger the loop.

```cpp
string getop()
{
  string op;
  int check = 1; 
  cout << "Enter an operator (+ - / *): ";
  cin >> op;
  if ((op != "+") || (op != "-") || (op != "/") || (op != "*"))
  {
    check = 0;
  }
  while (check == 0) // while the input is not a valid operator
  {
    cout << "Invalid operator, please enter a valid operator: ";
    cin >> op;
    if ((op == "+") || (op == "-") || (op == "/") || (op == "*"))
      check = 1;
  }

  return op;
}
```

the problem is, even when the user enters an operator on the first run through, the while loop still executes.

Comment: `if ((op != "+") || (op != "-") || (op != "/") || (op != "*"))` this comparison is wrong. At least 3 of these will always be true, so if you `or` them together, you get `true` every time. Do it like your second time instead. Have `check` start out at `0` and do `if ((op == "+") || (op == "-") || (op == "/") || (op == "*"))` to see if you should put it to `1`.

Comment: @Blaze it's a bummer. This comment alone has more explanation than 2/3 of the answers at the moment. If only you'd left this as answer so it could be recognized as such.

Comment: `if (!...)` followed by `while (!...)` could be simply replaced by `do { } while (!...);`. This would prevent code duplication.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but the code doesn't need all those parentheses. `if (op == "+" || op == "-" || op == "/" || op == "*")` works just fine. `==` has higher precedence than `||`, which really is the only thing that would make sense.

Comment: @scohe001 thanks for the acknowledgement. I was in a hurry so I didn't have time for an elaborate answer, but it looks like the current answers are good and elaborate now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a logic error:

```
if ((op != "+") || (op != "-") || (op != "/") || (op != "*"))
```

this will always yield `true` no matter what `op` is.

You want:

```
if ((op != "+") && (op != "-") && (op != "/") && (op != "*"))
```

---

A very good practise is to name your logical events. Also, AND chaining negations is rather unintuitive (and also unreadable). So an even better alternative would be:

```
bool is_valid = (op == "+") || (op == "-") || (op == "/") || (op == "*");

if (!is_valid)
    check = 0;
```

---

You also shouldn't `use namespace std;` - you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) why.

Comment: Why is it better to create another (unneeded) local variable? (also note that you accidentally left the OR's in on that new code)

Comment: @scohe001 to improve readability drasticly. This is considered good practise. And the OR's are intentional, as this is the positive case.

Comment: Ahh my fault, I misread there. Do note that this same conditional statement will be checked again in the while loop, so you'll end up having to duplicate this code again anyways. I still think just a `while(op != "+" && op != .... ) {` without any of the if's and the int variable would be way cleaner. But to each their own.

Comment: Thank you for responding, now i wont use namespace anymore, and i fixed the issue

Comment: @scohe001 I thought so too, but I frequently received a comment that one shall always name their events. like the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56288821/lambda-expression-to-return-bool-in-if-statement/56288924#56288924)

Comment: Meh. Do what you think is most pretty/readable. To me this is not, but I can understand that you may disagree.

Comment: I think it's one step towards writing expressive code. Code that speaks for itself.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
(op != "+") && (op != "-") && (op != "/") && (op != "*")
```

Operator `||` is `or` operator (alternative, one or another is enough). You want operator `&&`, which forces all conditions to be true together.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, i cant believe i missed this

Comment: @berg95 - if you keep programming, be assured you will do *much* dumber stuff than that.  After the first decade or so, you get used to asking "HOW could I be so stupid?"

Answer (score 3):

You want to use AND (`&&`), not OR (`||`):

```
if ((op != "+") && (op != "-") && (op != "/") && (op != "*"))
{
  check = 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem the answer would be a lot better with an explanation on how/why it does.  Remember that your answer is not just for the user that asked the question but also for all the other people that find it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is right here:

```cpp
if ((op != "+") || (op != "-") || (op != "/") || (op != "*"))
{
    check = 0;
}
```

Suppose `op` is assigned a value of `"+"`, that would mean that these conditions all evaluate to true: `op != "-"`, `op != "/"`, `op != "*"`.

Since you are using the OR (`||`) operator, `check` will be assigned a value of `0` if *any* of those conditions are true. In fact, one of those four conditions will *always* be true no matter what value `op` has.

You should use AND (`&&`) instead so that `check` is assigned 0 when all of the conditions are true:

```cpp
if ((op != "+") && (op != "-") && (op != "/") && (op != "*"))
{
    check = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you have a chain of assertions joined by `&&`, normally the negation consists in negate all the assertions and change all the `&&` operators by `||` or viceversa.

You changed all the asserrtions, negating them, but you forgot to change the `||` by `&&`.

Look for Demorgan's theorem in Google.